# What type of recursion is being depicted here?

Tags: php, recursion, computer-science

Consider the following PHP code:

```
function awesome(array $array): void {
    foreach ($array as $a) {
            if (!is_string($a)) {
                    awesome($a);
            }
    }
}

awesome(array('a' => array('abc'), 'b' => array('def'), 'c' => array('ghi')));
```

What type of recursion is being depicted here?

I understand linear recursion is a type of recursion where the recursive function is called exactly once. In this case, the recursive function is being called once however, the function call is within an iterative loop.

Surely, linear recursion is occurring here and not some other type of recursion.

Comment: What are you looking for exactly?

Comment: @A.Gille just the name/type of recursion being used here... do you perhaps know if this is an example of linear recursion or is another type of recursion occurring here? Type as in the English word, not type as in a user defined type.

Comment: It is not linear recursion as you can have more than one recursive call per recursion. I believe it is called "multiple recursion".

Comment: @A.Gille awesome() is only being called once on each iteration... so I'm fairly certain this is not an example of "multiple recursion"

Comment: @A.Gille also, awesome() is being called multiple times horizontally (or in series) and not in the same iteration

Answer (score 0):

This is nested recursion since the call of the root function is dependent on a condition. Other people are saying multiple recursion but this is incorrect, as multiple recursion suggests a different value of $a every time.

Comment: I've been told that this is actually tree recursion. Is this correct or is it actually nested recursion.

Comment: @SvzPkxBOjxO Yes, it's tree recursion. Tree recursion is where the value changes with every call of the function.

Comment: Why did you initially call it nested recursion? Was that just a guess?